# VideoJS playback under Firefox using MP4?

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I know that Video JS needs a WebM source to play back video. Yet I have seen sites that seem to play back MP4s in Firefox using Video JS?

How is this possible?

Check this out http://www.painandgainmovie.co.uk/instagram/

Its pulling MP4 files straight from a JSON that looks like its from Instagram.

Instagram only serves MP4 files... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the extra detail. I understand now. So your problem is that you would like to use mp4, and want to know if this is likely to work with VideoJS. You have read that they abandoned support for mp4, leaving only WebM - but you notice playing mp4 videos appear to work all the same.

According to [this page on the VideoJS website](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/questions/501-firefox-and-mp4), VideoJS can still display mp4 video in Firefox by passing it to the Flash plugin.

So it looks like you *can* use mp4, providing your visitors have Adobe Flash installed, and enabled.

Comment: Is the question really "how is it possible to play video with a programming language?"

I hope this is not a viral marketing attempt.

Comment: Sorry but you guys read the question? I know the tech is Video JS. I wanted to know if its possible to push MP4 videos in Firefox even though Firefox says it needs a WebM source.

The situation am facing is that on PC MP4 files play fine in Firefox... 

In Mac... it just won't play the MP4 and needs a WebM source.

I want to avoid having 2 sets of the same file just for one browser on Mac.

Comment: I think I was just grumpy that your question caused me to watch the Pain&Gain trailer ;) Kidding, my bad, thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Oh also, that tailer mp4 plays just fine on my Mac with Firefox 24. If I right-click, I can see that VideoJS has indeed wrapped it with a Flash player. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that now. I basically ended up rewriting my code to serve both MP4 and WEBM. OGV seems to have fallen off completely. Frustrating because it seems so silly to have to transcode 2 types of file to hit every browser. 

VideoJS Flash fallback player is not as extended as the HTML5 video player so the complex functionality doesn't work with the Flash fall back.

Comment: I accepted your suggestion anyway as you took the time to look at my issue. Thanks.